# Can I debug Javascript of a Web Application inside Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

I have been using VS2013 to develop my code which is an AngularJS application that talks to a back-end web server running ASP.NET Web API. I click on the build button, opening the application in the browser and then using Chrome Developer tools to debug the Javascript.

Now I am looking into the idea of using WebStorm. When using that to develop my application will I still have to use the Chrome Developer tools to do all my Javascript debugging as the application is running or is there some way that WebStorm allows me to debug within the WebStorm client?

Note I did see some answers here on SO relating to this question but these are very old and I wonder if new things have been added to the recent versions.

Comment: javascript debugger in webstorm is both powerful and well documented. Try reading the docs. JetBrains also has lots of videos for their products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can debug js code in vs2013 if you use Internet Explorer for the start browser.